# Getting shapefile of river from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, overpass-api, josm

I do not want to download the whole map of an area. I just want rivers and other waterbodies present in an area in shapefiles so that I can use them in QGIS. I tried geofabrik but it is giving whole map and that also of full country while i need data of a city. Right now I am trying JOSM. will update you when it will works.

Comment: what is the area of interest?

Comment: Natural Earth Rivers might be a better source http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-rivers-lake-centerlines/

Comment: Unfortunately Natural earth does not contains data of India.

Comment: [This](http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=pantnagar#map=10/29.0706/79.5753) is the area of which I need all waterbodies.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [Overpass Turbo API](http://overpass-turbo.eu/)!

First, I'd go to [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org),

You can either

1) Search for the feature you're after. I chose "south platte river", which runs through Denver. This gives the fields and tags that are used by OSM to store the data:

[image]

2) Identify the tags and values of the features you're after by

1. Zooming all the way into the map
2. Click on the layers icon on the right (the three sheets of paper)
3. Click on the last menu entry (`Map data` or something similar in your language)
4. The features on the map turn blue (make sure you're zoomed in far enough to see
5. Click on the feature you're after
6. The Tags and Values appear on left side of the screen, and you can proceed below...

[image]

Then go on over to the Overpass Turbo page, then click Wizard

Using information, the *name* value is South Platte River, and the *waterway* value is river, so you can build a query like this:

```
name="South Platte River" and waterway=river
```

Then click "build and run query"

[image]

The query will run and the result will show on the map:

[image]

Next click the "Export" option:

I like the geoJSON option

Click "Save"

Open the file in QGIS, and away you go!

[image]

You can do a 'save as' to save it as a new type of vector layer...

In your case, you could also use the `waterway=river` query to get all the rivers in the area you're after, and you can draw a manual selection box to narrow down the geography.

[image]

@underdark showed me this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i am still unable to follow you.
 I want waterbodies of [this](http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=pantnagar#map=10/29.0706/79.5753) area.
What should I write in overpass turbo webpage?

Comment: I just updated the answer above: in the overpass API, use the little find tool to find Haldwani, India. Then use the 'manual select bbox' to draw around the area you want, then use the wizard to run a waterway=river query... you might tweak it to find some other features using the OSM page i mentioned above, then build them into the query on Overpass.

Comment: thank you very much. But I still have 1 problem. 
it only selects rivers. I want lakes in them also.

Comment: give me an example of a lake you're after... the name...

Comment: you can see that [this](http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=pantnagar#map=14/28.9493/79.5971) lake is present in the original area but it is not selected when the query is run in overpass. This lake has no name shown in osm.

Comment: if that lake has no name, then you're out of luck... you can always use the OSM plugin for QGIS to download everything in your QGIS map extent... otherwise, go into open street map and give that lake a name using existing conventions for lakes in the area... all around a good open street map exercise!

Comment: okay. I will try osm plugin then. Thanks for your time. It was very helpful..

Comment: I used the tool with this script `[out:json][timeout:25];
nwr["name"="Mahaweli"]["waterway"="river"]({{bbox}});
out geom;` but I can't export it as a png, everytime I do it the line is very off from the map.

Answer (score 7):

The new [QuickOSM plugin for QGIS](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) provides a nice GUI to use the Overpass API. You can specify the key-value pairs that you want and it also offers user-friendly ways to filter by location: either bounding box or even by just specifying the region name like "Austria" for features within Austrian borders.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter your OSM data with GDAL by bounding box and by attributes and save the results directly into any vector format that is supported by GDAL. Install GDAL version 1.10 or higher and read the manual pages of the OSM driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html and ogr2ogr http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. This task with rivers and lakes can be done with default settings but it is often necessary to edit the osmconf.ini file first.

Rivers can be found from the OSM data by tag "waterway=river" and GDAL saves them into layer "lines". Lakes you find by "natural=water" and they go to layer "multipolygons". If your aim is to make shapefiles you must save rivers and lakes to different files because lines and polygons can't be saved into a same shapefile.

Examples below are using the india-latest.osm.pbf file from geofabrik. The basic commands to use:

```bash
# See : http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html , http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html 
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -spat 76 22 77 23 -sql "select * from lines where waterway='river'" rivers.shp india-latest.osm.pbf --config ogr_interleaved_reading yes
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -spat 76 22 77 23 -sql "select * from multipolygons where natural='water'" lakes.shp india-latest.osm.pbf --config ogr_interleaved_reading yes
```

Place your own BBOX into the -spat parameter in EPSG:4326 units.

Ogr2ogr is flexible and has lots of options. Read the manual page carefully.