# Is there a way to identify features on OpenStreetMap.org?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there an identify features option for OpenStreetMap.org (OSM.org)?

Stemming from this question: [How to get shapefile of river from OpenStreetMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98371/how-to-get-shapefile-of-river-from-openstreetmap/98374) I'm looking for the ability to use OSM.org to figure out the tags and values for features I want to download through the Overpass API, or even QGIS for that matter.

If there was a way to use OSM.org to browse the data of OSM through the map interface, then click on a feature to get the information about it.

Currently, if you know what a feature is called, you can search for it, and you get the information I'm referring to as the output:

[image]

This would be the exact information I would expect if I were to use an Identify button and click on a feature on OSM.org.

This would greatly help, as the first referenced post suggests, the ability to pull down specific data from Overpass API or QGIS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Zoom into the map as close as possible
2. Click on the layers icon on the right (the three sheets of paper)
3. Click on the last menu entry (`Map data` or something similar in your language)

Then all lines get blue, and you can identify them with the mouse.

Other option is to install the JOSM editor, and download a small portion of the area of your interest. You don't need to register for downloading only.