# How to export tracks of a specific polygon in overpass-turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to export some features (in this case `route=hiking`) that are inside a specific boundary. So not the boundary box that I can choose through the pan tool, but all the routes that for example belong to a national park.

Can I do this with the wizard?

I've founded [this example](http://tinyurl.com/kaz5bvj) in the OSM wiki. I'm trying to perform something like that.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to use a custom boundary http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98371/how-to-get-shapefile-of-river-from-openstreetmap/98374#98374

Comment: @mapBaker - it's great answer, but not for this question. Matteo wrote it's not about bbox...

Comment: @mapBaker - yes, great answer, but not what I'm looking for...

Comment: you should just download the features via the bounding box and clip them using QGIS or the like. I don't think overpass can do the clipping that you're after.

Comment: @maoBaker - fine, that's what I'm doing right now. Clipping directly in overpass could spare resources and speed up the download..

Comment: follow @mapBaker - overpass is tool that allows downloading of selective data but I don't heard about editing data. It's possible to download all data intersecting a polygon like boundary, but I don't think it's possible to clip this data to polygon. If you need to automate this functionality maybe you should use postgis database?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to describe a [custom polygon](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_region_by_polygon) instead of a bounding box for the Overpass API. And with the help of overpass turbo and its [location filters](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard#Location_Filters) you can even query for named objects.

See [this example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/41z) for all ways inside the *"Belair National Park"*. I created it via the overpass-turbo wizard by searching for *highway in "Belair National Park"*. But as you can see, the ways don't get cropped at the border of the park. This is something you will have to do yourself if needed.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now it is clear that through overpass I can download raw data and then I should use another software to clean/clip them.