# Exporting OpenStreetMap data to shapefile

Tags: openstreetmap, export

I want to have river paths and Parks/natural/Landscape shapefiles in our region:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/note/1070052#map=11/45.1259/38.4660&layers=CN

How should I export this layer to a shapefile?

Before this I googled it a lot but I couldn't find anyway.

Comment: This is not a direct download from the page you provided, but you can get OSM layers from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/russia.html

Comment: If you are a QGIS user, the QuickOSM extension allows you to easily extract OpenStreetMap by entering the tag of the object you want to extract and the geographical location. I can give you more information if this solution suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
[How to get shapefile of river from OpenStreetMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98371/how-to-get-shapefile-of-river-from-openstreetmap) plus QuickOSM extension that a user here mentioned it.
I'm using ArcGIS.